# Why do Manga & Anime defuse tragic situations so often?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production

Why do Manga and Anime defuse so often tragic situations? Moments that can be tragic/serious are often immediately defused by some hilarious moment and some stupid face of the characters. I personally find that disturbing that a plot cannot focus on something serious for a little while. Is that a stylistic choice or just a way to target a particular audience (i.e. children).

Comment: Do you have any example of this situation ?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Anticlimax Do you mean these sort of situations?

Comment: yes thanks! as far as I know I readed once a couple of mangas and they were full of anticlimax

Comment: you need to read/watch more anime. For example: anohana or shigatsu wa kimi no uso, or uh... madoka..

Comment: @ton.yeung To be fair, Shigatsu wa Kimi no Uso is actually _really_ bad about this - far worse than you'd expect from an otherwise good drama. The one that always comes to mind is the bit in the last episode (where, you know, important things happen) when Kashiwagi makes some off-color joke about BL at a wholly narratively-inappropriate time.

Comment: Those are the best shows, the ones that make you both  laugh and cry

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, I gather you don't like the use of Anti-Climax in M&A as a medium. Though it can be jarring, Anti Climax can be great if used correctly.

> Anticlimaxes can work well if it's clear that the subversion of audience expectations is the point, either for humorous purposes (such as the Anticlimax Cut) or as a more serious commentary on the genre of the work. If the Anticlimax is unintentional, however, or if the author's purpose just isn't sufficiently clear to the audience, the result is serious audience frustration. Use caution.

I think the root cause of this problem is discussed quite well on TV Tropes.

> Not all anticlimaxes are intentional, though. Oftentimes, they are caused when the story writes itself into a corner. Other times, it's caused when the writer realizes that their planned solution just wouldn't make sense compared with the logical one. Sometimes, it's caused when there are teams of writers that don't communicate very well. The planned resolution of a Story Arc is nullified by another writer, who might have written out the plot device intended. Sometimes, in the case of film and television, it's caused by budget constraints or unexpected cancellation. It's rather rare for unintentional anticlimaxes to show up in single works, usually popping up in long serials where there isn't a chance to unobtrusively go back and rewrite some pivotal moments to set up the proper climax.

The problems stated above are quite common in the Manga and Anime industry and thus as you seem to have found out can lead to disappointing endings to a great story.

Source: [You've been warned TV Tropes link. Anti Climax](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Anticlimax)

Comment: Maybe this is not exactly anticlimax what I was searching for. In example someone just get refused by his love, and in the immediatly following scene some character do a stupid face, nothing to do with "endings", but more about scenes.

Comment: @DarioOO Anit Climax is not just for "endings" either. Each scene has a pattern, there is the reason, buildup and climax. However sometimes the author may diffuse/complete the scene using anti climatic ending. One of the most famous example is the rise of Madara Uchiha who was destoyed at his peak in just 4 Black and White Panels in Naruto. The "stupid face" may be the writers way to try and complete the situation. The second spoilers lists down several causes for "unintentional" anti-climax.

Answer (score 2):

I would believe this is something of psychology where it makes the situation funnier; it's like after tasting some salt, the sugar will taste much sweeter. If I try to explain this using a more understandable way, think of the number line: the funny side is to the right and the serious side is to the left and you are at the 0 point right in the middle feeling no emotions. When things start to get serious, you move to the left and feel serious at for example -3, but then they drop a joke which makes you laugh and you move to the right. Because 0 is the neutral point where you feel no emotions, you have to move past 0 to feel happy so you have to be at least 1 or above. The funnier the joke, the higher the number. Now, because you are starting from -3 rather than 0, it gives you 3 more than if they just throw the joke at you in the start. This can work the other way around as well. This is mostly why they use this technique.

If they do it wrong, or when they see people like you who don't enjoy these sorts of things, it doesn't work. From what I have seen, these are mostly used in slice of life and shounen manga/anime. In shounen, they will get serious, then someone makes a joke, then they get deep and serious again. If you look at genres such as horror, this "trope" practically doesn't exist. An example would be EVA (I believe): there is no funny bits in there, it's serious throughout the show, but this might differ from person to person.

Comment: Yes, you explained well what I'm talking about, so maybe someone now can cite some source about that

Comment: Eva actually does use comedy in the early episodes but there's almost none starting from Episode 14 or so. Don't know about Rebuild.

Comment: @Torisuda sorry about that, haven't watched it in so long that i don't remember

Comment: @DarioOO i can't remember the name but i'm pretty sure its a psychology thing, i might ask my teachers and get back to you

Comment: @Dragon No worries, the later episodes do tend to blot out the early ones that had comedy. I watched the series again about four years ago and the comedy parts really stuck out. They were so jarring compared to the dark tone of Episodes 1-4 and Episodes 14-26. Plus, when I first saw Eva I was young and very new to anime, and I thought the comedy parts were hilarious, but when I watch them now they seem kinda dated.